# Keyframe text translate and rotate not working

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transitions

I like to translateY and rotate a `h1` element to its place. but the translation doesn't work and while rotating the text leaves its place and gets back, but i want it to be in its place the whole time.

code:

```
.article1 h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 130px;
    margin-bottom: 12px; 
    animation: tilt 2s ease 3;
} 
@keyframes tilt{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(200px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

I need the h1 to come to its location from 200px top, and do a 360deg Y rotation while coming down, is it possible?

Comment: can you share your html code?

Comment: ```<article class="article1">
        <h1>What we do.</h1>
        <h3>We provide Top-Quality Plants you choose right to your doorstep</h3>
        <button class="button">Explore</button>
    </article> ```

Comment: you can do nested divs and put an animation on each.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rotateY` transform is overwriting your `translateY` transform, you need to   include both `rotateY` and `translateY` in the one transform line

Try this:

```
@keyframes tilt{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(200px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotateY(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, both of them works now, but still when the elements rotates it moves to the right and gets back left, is there any way to make it rotate in a single place?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking. Your CSS says the animation happens 3 times, perhaps `animation: tilt 2s ease 1;` would fix it?